# How 2 remote endpoints that are both behind NAT establish peer-to-peer communication (e.g. how do cloud security cameras really work)?

Tags: networking, video, webcam, camera, cloud

If for example both the cloud camera and my remote client (phone or PC) are behind NAT, this means that both the camera and the camera client on the phone open connections to the cloud provider, right? Does this mean that the actual video stream will always go through the cloud? Do all these Chinese brands that sell thousands of cloud cameras have the ability to relay so many video feeds at the same time through their cloud infrastructure? Or is there a networking technique such that the camera can send the feed peer-to-peer, directly to my phone/PC IP address (after registering to the cloud)? (suppose router UPnP is disabled)

This same question could be applied to other kind of cloud applications too, like remote desktop (TeamViewer, AnyDesk, etc.), Skype, etc.

Comment: I altered the initial title ("how do cloud security cameras really work?") significantly in order to make it less vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this means that both the camera and the camera client on the phone open connections to the cloud provider, right?

Yes. It's a common technique; even the worst home routers will allow a connection to remain alive as long as it has activity every few minutes.

> Does this mean that the actual video stream will always go through the cloud? [...] Or is there a networking technique such that the camera can send the feed peer-to-peer

It depends.

It's completely possible that the cloud service is only needed for initial handshake (NAT hole-punching), similar to how some online games and software such as Skype still successfully establish peer-to-peer connections even when both ends are behind NAT.

There are several techniques, and STUN is a commonly used standard "helper" protocol for this purpose. (If you've ever seen the Xbox message "Your network is behind a symmetric NAT", it's shown because this NAT type makes inbound connections really difficult compared to other types.) For more information see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling
- https://samy.pl/pwnat/

But it's also completely possible that the entire stream is relayed through the service provider. In many cases (again, with Skype as an example) the provider offers a relaying service but it's only used in situations where NAT hole-punching doesn't succeed, so only a small part of all customers ends up using it so the costs aren't as bad as otherwise.

If the question is about privacy, then it depends on how much you trust the provider's security practices in general. The stream *could* be end-to-end encrypted so that only the app (but not the relay) will be able to see its contents – or it might not.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this... actually I find the techniques described in "hole punching" quite interesting... Too bad my question title seems a little vague and deceives other users into down-voting it.